# Doing a code-along video, and this is the exact same code but i get an error and can not seem to find the issue with it

Tags: python-3.x

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

all_quotes = []
site = "http://quotes.toscrape.com/"
res = requests.get(site)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
quotes = soup.find_all('div', attrs = {'class':'quote'})
for quote in quotes:
    all_quotes.append({
        "text": quotes.find(class_='text'),
        "author": quotes.find(class_='author'),
        "url-bio": quotes.find("a")["href"]
    })
```

error:

```
$ python scraping_project.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraping_project.py", line 12, in <module>
    "text": quotes.find(class_='text'),
  File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1578, in __getattr__
    "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Comment: I think you mean `quote.find` and not `quotes.find`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to use `quote` instead of `quotes`:

```
for quote in quotes:
    all_quotes.append({
        "text": quote.find(class_='text'),
        "author": quote.find(class_='author'),
        "url-bio": quote.find("a")["href"]
    })
```

`quotes` references the list of items that you get from `soup.find_all(...)`.

To understand what `quote` is, you'll need to learn about [for loops](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops).